# Keybindings in JavaFX using Lambda expressions not working

Tags: java, macos, user-interface, lambda

I have an error saying that my conditions are always false. Basically the convention for closing applications on OSX is using the key combination "COMMAND+W"

I am trying to replicate this in my program.

```
  scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if ((e.getCode() == KeyCode.COMMAND) && (e.getCode() == KeyCode.W)) {
            controller.exitClick();
        }
    });
```

It works if I only have the first condition but of course I do not want the user to close the application by just pressing W.

The controller is just an instance of my controller class where I borrow the exit function from because I have custom made exit and minimize buttons on my application.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The event `setOnKeyPressed` detects *one* key at a time, you can't check two of them in one condition since it can only apply to one.

What you can do is create several `boolean` variables (one for each key) and in `setOnKeyPressed` you have conditions which check each key separately and if the current key pressed is one of them, you set the matching variable to `true`. After checking which key was pressed, you check both variables, if both are `true` then someone pressed both keys.

One small problem is that the variables are never turned to `false`, what if someone is not pressing the key? You could use `setOnKeyReleased` which is a key event called when a key is released. check for each key separately and set the condition variables to `false` if the key was released.

So that should do it. If you need an example code, just ask.

**EDIT**

The example bellow showcases detection of multi-key press in JavaFX.

First I need to define boolean variables which save whether or not my key is pressed. They should be class variables.

```
boolean keyCommand = false;
boolean keyW = false;
```

Then we need to add 2 events to our scene:

onKeyPressed event will detect when each one of our key is pressed. Remember that the event is called separately for each key.

onKeyReleased event will detect that our keys are no longer pressed. This event is called for each key separately as well.

```
scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
         if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.COMMAND)
                   keyCommand = true;
         else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.W)
                   keyW = true;

          if(keyCommand && keyW)
                 //both are pressed
                 doSomething();

 });
```

Now to the second event:

```
scene.setOnKeyReleased(e -> {
       if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.COMMAND)
              keyCommand = false;
        else if(e.getCode() === KeyCode.W)
              keyW = false;
});
```

And that's it. Now boolean variables might not be the perfect way to hold the data, `BooleanProperty` might be preferable, but it should work as well.

Comment: Can I have some example code? I barely understand what you are getting at.

Comment: See, I had an idea something of the like which I implemented but I got the error that variables used in lambda expressions should be final or effectively final. So the two boolean variables cannot be used.

Comment: @compute did you define them as class variables, not in a method?

Comment: Yes and it is now saying that both `if(keyCommand && keyW)` is always false

Comment: It should work, it works for me (just tested). It could be one of 2 things: you missed something when adding it, or you are not focused on the scene. If you use a control on your window it seems that scene key events are not recognized because it is no longer focused.

Comment: A much more concise and accurate way to do this is to use [`isShortcutDown`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#isShortcutDown--), or the equivalents for Control, Shift etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by instead using integers and one method only.

I do not know of the potential vulnerabilities to doing it this way but here is the code.

```
    scene.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.SHIFT)
            count++;
        else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.W)
            count++;
        if(count == 3)
            controller.exitClick();
    });
```

There is some global value `int count = 1;`